# PHP - Get Time Zone By Country Name

Tags: php

I want to get the time zone abbreviation of visitor and for this purpose i am using the below code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
$visitor_country_code = $details->country . 'T';
```

From this i got the first two letters of country name and concatenated 'T'.But this is working only for few countries.I tested it by changing proxy and it worked for Pakistan and then i tried for USA and it gave me error

> DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (AEDT)

Can someone help me to get the country code of all countries?

Comment: I don't see how you you can get this error from the code you posted above. Please show us your whole code, because the first 3 lines you posted have nothing to do with a DateTimeZone Object. And can I ask you why you concate a "t" at the end of the country code?

Comment: you can use ip-api.com it will return timezone

Comment: It's not a reliable way for getting the country from the IP address, I just tested it with my IP address and the `country` was **empty** which means you should add a test `empty()` or you'll get an error!

Comment: http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?username=demo

Comment: http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&username=demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `https://freegeoip.net/json/[IP address]` to get all the information you want.